# How do I stop my program from executing after a dialog box appears

Tags: vb.net

I have a problem where my code, a simple order form requires certain information. When the user does not enter a piece of information, the program displays a dialog box, and then after the user hits Okay, it still calculates the information. I am new to VB so here is the code snippet:

```
 If (CheckBox3.Checked = False And blueBlackQuantityTextBox.Text <> "" And blueBlackQuantityTextBox.Text > 0) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please check item you wish to purchase", "No Item Selected",
      MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        Stop
    End If

    Const whiteBlackDicePrice = 6.25
    Const redBlackDicePrice = 5.0
    Const blueBlackDicePrice = 7.5
    Const tax = 0.05

    Dim whiteBlackSubTotal As Double = whiteBlackQuantityTextBox.Text *      whiteBlackDicePrice
    Dim redBlackSubTotal As Double = redBlackQuantityTextBox.Text * redBlackDicePrice
    Dim blueBlackSubtotal As Double = blueBlackQuantityTextBox.Text * blueBlackDicePrice
    'newBalanceResultLabel.Text = String.Format("{0:C2}", newBalance)

    Dim subtotal As Double = whiteBlackSubTotal + redBlackSubTotal + blueBlackSubtotal

    whiteBlackTotalsLabel.Text = String.Format("{0:C2}", whiteBlackSubTotal)
    redBlackTotalsLabel.Text = String.Format("{0:C2}", redBlackSubTotal)
    blueBlackTotalsLabel.Text = String.Format("{0:C2}", blueBlackSubtotal)

    subtotalResultLabel.Text = String.Format("{0:C2}", subtotal)
```

putting a STOP after each IF statement, results in the program crashing, and I can only have the dialog box say: Okay.

Please help!

Comment: I have a temporary solution. dim count as integer = 0, and after each IF statement add count by 1. If count is = 0, then continue with the program.

Can anyone provide a better solution?

Comment: you only show one IF statement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here how you should write your program

```
Private sub MySub()

    If not ConditionsValidated() Then

        MessageBox.Show("Please check item you wish to purchase") ' MsgBox with a single button always returns Ok. Here you don't even need to tell to show Ok - this is default.
        Return
    End If

    ' your code is running here

end sub

private function ConditionsValidated() as Boolean

    ' Validate your controls here

end sub
```

I would also NOT show "Error" message box if someone didn't select something. Error means your application encountered a serious error. This is why there are validators that could display a small red dot next to invalid control, or make back color of control red, etc

Answer (score 0):

```
 If (CheckBox3.Checked = False And blueBlackQuantityTextBox.Text <> "" 
       And blueBlackQuantityTextBox.Text > 0) Then

    If MessageBox.Show("Please check item you wish to purchase", 
           "No Item Selected",
           MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error) = DialogResult.OK Then
          Stop
    End If
 End if
```

The msgbox message and action dont seem to match.  Its not clear that "No item" will END the program (or break to debug in the designer).  Maybe you mean `Exit Sub`?  Further, since they have one choice, OK, it will always end the program

At any rate, `MessageBox` is a function returning a `DialogResult` you can evaluate.  you dont have your configured that way

Comment: Sorry here is what is happening: 1. Run program. 2. User makes an error. 3. Dialog box shows saying "Please check...purchase" 4. Information still calculates (the code AFTER the if check.) 

I would like after the Error message shows, the user can change the info, without the code calculating after.

Comment: The original question was to make the program STOP after a MsgBox, the above explains that - you were not checking the result.  NOW what it sounds like you want is something like TS answer - CHECK the data and do dialogs with the user SEPERATE from calculations.  Or instead of STOP, do EXIT SUB or change the IF structure to use an ELSE

Answer (score 0):

Simple Solution for this. Use below code at any place it will stop execution immediately.

```
Response.End
```